# Using the DB API to test against a trimmed value?

Tags: 7, database

I want to use the DB API (Drupal 7) to do a query like:

```
select my_field from table where trim(my_field) <> ''
```

where `my_field` is a text field.  My goal is to not get any values in the result that are made up of one or more spaces. (This is a greatly simplified example query, but you get the idea.) Is there any way to get that call to trim() in there? The only thing I could imagine trying was:

```
$query->condition('trim(my_field)', '', '<>');
```

which doesn't work at all.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectQuery::where()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Awhere/7.x) for more complex requirements:

```
$query->where('trim(my_field) <> :val', ['val' => '']);
```